# How to configure ASPNET Core with Docker using VSTS to build, run tests and deploy to Azure with Unit Tests and Environment Variables

Tags: visual-studio, azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to do something incredibly trivial I thought but apparently this needs to be hard. And yes there are bits and pieces throughout stack overflow but they're either out of date or don't actually work.

1. I've got an asp.net core site that I've dockerized with the add/docker/linux command.
2. In VSTS I can build the image and publish it with 2 docker-compose items.
3. And then I can release the image with the release management.

What I can't figure out how to do:

1. run dotnet test on my image and report the results to VSTS
2. Setup environment variables on Azure App Service Container that get properly passed into the image when its run.

On #1, I cannot find any up-to-date documentation on how to set it up so that while developing unit tests don't run unless specifically specified (and if I tell it to run tests in visual studio they should run in the docker image! I can get them to run always, but that's a waste of time while developing if they run every time you start debugging!).

And I cannot figure out how to use either docker-compose or the new VS.net 2017 15.8 way with just docker run commands to run the tests. It seems to me that I would need a new dockerfile just for the tests to run and have it generate and then discard the image that was created. But I can't figure out how to do this or even if this is the right way.

How should this be setup to do unit tests? (I've gone through 5 pages of google search results and none of them work right.)

On #2, setting and application setting in the App Service does not pass the values in docker run. I've tried everything and they never get passed. How do you pass environment variables on Azure so that the run command gets the right -e parameters?

Answer (score 0):

For#1 you could use dotnet test command. This will generate a `.trx` file that VSTS can pick up and render a nice test report. You just need to setup the “Publish Test Results” task.

`dotnet test --logger trx --results-directory /var/temp`

More details please take a look at this blog: [Running your unit tests with Visual Studio Team Services and Docker Compose](https://medium.com/@christiansparre/running-your-unit-tests-with-visual-studio-team-services-and-docker-compose-3f82c9b95bf)

For#2 not totally get your point, if you want to override environment variable values on VSTS and use the value on Azure App Service Container. Please try this solution through powershell script:  [How to override values of environment variables on VSTS tasks](http://normalian.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/03/29/073622)

Beside suggest you also go through this blog shows how Docker [Deployment to Azure App Service (Linux) using VSTS](https://almvm.azurewebsites.net/labs/vstsextend/docker/) including both CI and CD. Which maybe helpful to you.

Comment: I get the test command, however VS.net 2017 15.8 completely eliminates docker-compose.  Also, I'm assuming that the dockerfile referenced in the article is in the test project and not the web project? (It's not totally clear)

On VSTS I get how to set the environment variables. Just pass them as -e on the command it executes. My issue is on Azure App Service for Containers. Nothing I do actually causes the docker run command it executes to past -e <appsetting>  They simply are never added. using az cli or the UI.

Comment: Also, this doesn't address having VS.net execute the tests in docker instead of directly. The current way defeats the purpose. The tests should always be run in the same docker image as the app is going to run to ensure consistency.